# FileUpload control event

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I want to know how to raise an event for fileupload control....
In my project, as soon as I select a file(Image) it should show FILENAME,EXTENSION & SIZE in the labels given below.

Pls reply me....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Until HTML5 becomes mainstream, it is completely impossible to do this without uploading the entire file to the server.  (Except maybe with Flash)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible you need first to upload the file and then get it's information and add them to labels, otherwise you need to use third party plug-in to able you to do that such as flash or java applets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get file information as soon as you select the file.

```
int filesize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
string fileextension = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
```